# Prepopulate Core Data in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

There seem to be some modifications to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` method is iOS 5.
I am trying to get a prepopulated database ... it doesn't seem to work, no crash but none of the data seems to exist... Any suggestions?

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataModel.sqlite"];

    /*
     Set up the store.
     For the sake of illustration, provide a pre-populated default store.
     */
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storePath absoluteString]]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataModel" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:[storePath absoluteString] error:NULL];
        }
    }


    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataModel.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: I can't tell you why this doesn't work but I can tell you that the exact same code works for me. Is the sqlite database copied to your Documents folder?

Comment: @user1028028 hey there good answer you got. why don't you approve  Ivo Leko answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method that gives wrong absolute string. It is not really wrong, but is not suited for `NSFileManager` class.

The solution is simple. You need to write another method which I called `applicationDocumentsDirectory2`.

So first, go to header file of your AppDelegate and declare method:

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory2;
```

---

Now, go to the .m file, and define a method:

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory2 {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

---

And finally, just change `persistentStoreCoordinator` method into:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSError *error = nil;

   NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory2] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"DataModel.sqlite"];

    /*
     Set up the store.
     For the sake of illustration, provide a pre-populated default store.
     */
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataModel" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            if(![fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);


            }
        } 
    }


    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataModel.sqlite"];

    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;

}
```

That's it! :)