# Preloaded Core Data Database in ios5 with UIManagedDocument

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

I am trying to include a pre-loaded Core Data database in my app.

I am using the solution given in this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683892/pre-load-core-data-database-in-ios-5-with-uimanageddocument) but it is not working.

Rather than copying out the database I have included in the app bundle, the savetoURL command just creates a new empty database file every time.

Anybody any idea why this might be?

Really appreciate any help, have been stuck on this for two days now.

Comment: The following document has the answer to your question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041278/prepopulate-core-data-in-ios-5

Comment: I've written a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683892/pre-load-core-data-database-in-ios-5-with-uimanageddocument/11713120#11713120